# prepend href with same class

Tags: jquery

I have the following code on the my page...

```
<a href="javascript:change_product_photo(2);"><img id="alternate_product_photo_2"    style="border-color:#666666;" src="/v/vspfiles/photos/00-6189-2S.jpg" border="1">
```

Sometimes there could be more of the `<a href="javascript:change_product_photo(4);">` and each one would have a higher index number 5, 6 ,7, etc.

What I want to do is for each and every instance of the href with `javascript:change_product_photo(x)` (where x is the index) remove both "_" from the `change_product_link` but leave the `(x)` index

My thought was to first add a class to all hrefs that contain `javascript:change_product_photo` and then modify all of the href;s with that class but I am lost on how to do this.

Here is what I got so far...

```
$("a[href*='javascript:change_product_photo']").addClass('link_fix');
```

Now I don't know how to remove the "_" from the url.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please visit http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try...

```
$("a[href^='javascript:change_product_photo']")
    .addClass('link_fix')
    .attr('href', function(i,v){
        return v.replace('_','');
    })
```

edit based on comment, note the `href*=` has changed to `href^=` ([start-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/))

[and read 'Easy Setter Functions' `function(i,v){...}`](http://jquery14.com/day-01/jquery-14) as of jQuery 1.4.x

Comment: Wow that was fast and it worked great, thanks so much. I realize this is not really the place to go into detail but I don't understand the function(i,v), can you explain it?

Comment: Sorry I spoke too soon. it doesn't work.
Below is the code that works but no clean If I had more links I has to make add more code manually

$("a[href*='javascript:change_product_photo(2)']").addClass('link_fix2');
$("a[href*='javascript:change_product_photo(3)']").addClass('link_fix3');
$("a[href*='javascript:change_product_photo(4)']").addClass('link_fix4');
$("a.link_fix2").attr('href', 'javascript:change_product_photo_fix(2)');
$("a.link_fix3").attr('href', 'javascript:change_product_photo_fix(3)');
$("a.link_fix4").attr('href', 'javascript:change_product_photo_fix(4)');

Comment: That was great and I verified that it does work. The href*= was not he issue it was the fact that I had an older version of jquery lib 1.3.2 and when you gave me the reason link to the function(i,v) statement it all cam together, LOL thanks