# remove text from a function (i think)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove the "_" in the "change_option". I managed to add the class ok but that's it

```
<select onchange="change_option('SELECT___100E___7',this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)" name="SELECT___100E___7" class="link_fix3">
```

Here is the code I have so far...

```
$("form select[onchange^='change_option']")
    .addClass('link_fix3')
    .attr('onchange', function(k,x){
     return x.replace('_','');})
```

Comment: Try putting the onchange even in jQuery, that way you don't have to worry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the internals, it seems you're trying to call `changeoption(name, value)`, you can do this entirely in jQuery, like this:

```
$("form select[onchange^='change_option']")
  .addClass('link_fix3')
  .change(function() {
    changeoption(this.name, $(this).val());
  });
```

Though with more details, this can probably be even simpler, for example is giving the `<select>` a class initially an option? That would make the selector much cleaner, then you can leave the initial `onchange` attribute off completely...you have to admit this looks prettier :)

```
<select name="SELECT___100E___7" class="link_fix3">
```

Script like this:

```
$("form select.link_fix3").change(function() {
  changeoption(this.name, $(this).val());
});
```

If you post what your `changeoption` function looks like, I could improve the answer to show additional simplifications, if any of these options I'm offering are do-able...I know the programmers control over markup varies widely, so let us know what options you *do* have.

Comment: Well the code posted does work!!!! The only reason for me adding the class is I though it work be needed to target the function but I see that will not be necessary so I removed the .addClass('link_fix3') code and it works just the same.

Thanks!!!

Comment: @user - Welcome :)  Be sure to accept answers via the checkmark on the left if it solves your problem, it also helps you get answers to future questions faster :)

Comment: Well like I said it does work but I think it not excatly as I thought it should. It seems that it changes the function name after the onchange in activated. Sorry if I do not explain it in proper terms. Any way to change the name and not the name as a rsult of the action?
I would expect the markup to be changed as soon as the page loads which is not the case here. I know it is working however because it is calling the changeoption function and not the change_option function. Hope you understand what I am trying to say?

Comment: @user - Is there a reason the original function needs to be there at all?  It depends how you're viewing markup, firebug, chrome console? (IE is *highly* unreliable here, it shows the original source)...also this is an event, it's not like a normal attribute, so don't think of it the same way, attaching the correct event handler by binding like I have above is the better approach in most cases.

Comment: No there is no reason for the original function to be there. Firebug BTW. I have a similar replace that Reigel helped me out before and that will show up in the markup but yours does not.

See this message...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962860/prepend-href-with-same-class

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood but let me clarify, the "onchange" is necessary, what is no longer necessary is the function name "change_option"

Comment: @user - If you just have an initial class, or another way to get the `<select>` with a jQuery selector, like `$("select.pickMe")` gets `<select class="pickMe">`, you can use my second solution above.  This allows you to move all the script into an external file as well, keeping it even cleaner...what about this approach *doesn't* work for your site?  It's the common way of doing things now since it offers numerous advantages, including smaller download/payload, faster loads, unobtrusive, easier to debug, etc.

Comment: well I tried the your second answer and that works as well..

$("form select").addClass("link_fix3");
$("form select.link_fix3").change(function() {
changeoption(this.name, $(this).val());
});

Just do not see the change_option changing in the markup like I would expect to see when the page finishes loading. Mystery to me but I can't complain, LOL
If you got nothing more you can think of I mark it answered, thanks so much

Comment: @user - You can see it bound in the console, if you do `$("form select").data("events")` you can see all bound handlers, for example `$("form select").data("events").change` will show the handler you just attached :)

Comment: Well I wish I knew how to do that, but it is ok it works and that's what is important, just wished I knew why, lol but thats why your the expert and I am not, lol, thx again

Answer (score 0):

just a thought... if you do this,

```
$("form select[onchange^='change_option']")
    .addClass('link_fix3')
    .attr('onchange', function(k,x){
     return x.replace('_','');})
```

the output would be,

```
onchange="changeoption('SELECT00E7',this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)" // notice your, 'SELECT___100E___7'
```

I suggest this,

```
$("form select[onchange^='change_option']")
        .addClass('link_fix3')
        .attr('onchange', function(k,x){
         return x.replace('change_option','changeoption');})
```

that is, if you really want to solve it that way...